# S3 static hosting AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a problem. I created an S3 bucket for hosting. In the properties settings, I used Static website hosting and index.html as index document. In the bucket policy I use this :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.com/*"
    }
]
```

}

When I try to open the website with my browser just with the URL mybucket.com I get an error with AccessDenied. When I use mybucket.com/index.html then it works.

What do I need to change so that it automatically uses the index.html as index file?

Thanks,

Syd

Comment: Is `mybucket.com` the long s3 bucket URL (eg: `mybucket.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`) or your own domain name (just `mybucket.com`)?

Comment: It's the own domain name not the bucket URL but the bucket name is just the domain name not the bucket url

Comment: And if you visit the s3 bucket URL do you have the same problem or does the site render properly?

Answer (score 0):

S3 itself has two URLs. If you want to publicly view the content (as it's a static website) - make sure that the URL you're using is `http://BUCKET.s3-website.REGION.amazonaws.com/` instead of `https://BUCKET.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/`.